Having problem with table structure not readable
I am creating the table in Overleaf using latex, but the size of the table is too small. Though my table has 6 columns ad even I am trying to fit in new page but still its size is coming too small to read. Find the code below:
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Comparative Synthesis of Community Detection Metrics}
\vspace{1em}
\label{tab:community_detection_synthesis}
\resizebox{.8\paperwidth}{!}{% Resize table to fit within page width

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{\LARGE{Graph Classification}} & \textbf{\LARGE{Algorithm Employed}} & \textbf{\LARGE{Mod. Measure}}& \textbf{\LARGE{Inertial Measure}} & \textbf{\LARGE{Comm. Count}} & \textbf{\LARGE{Shared Members}}\\ \hline

\LARGE{Standard Graph} & \LARGE{Louvain Algorithm \cite{r71}} & \LARGE{0.12 / 0.09} & \LARGE{0.39 / 0.22} & \LARGE{12 / 10} & \LARGE{10} \\ \hline
\LARGE{Informational Single Graph} & \LARGE{Combined Community Detection Algorithm \cite{r72}} & \LARGE{0.17 / 0.13} & \LARGE{0.82 / 0.60} & \LARGE{30 / 35} & \LARGE{32} \\ \hline
\LARGE{Composite Graph} & \LARGE{Generalized modularity optimization \cite{r73}} & \LARGE{ 0.21 / 0.18} & \LARGE{0.67 / 0.50} & \LARGE{20 / 16} & \LARGE{17} \\ \hline
\LARGE{Dynamic Composite Information Graph} & \LARGE{MCLDA} & \LARGE{0.25 / 0.21} & \LARGE{0.94 / 0.97} & \LARGE{24 / 9 }& \LARGE{4} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

And currently output is coming as
enter image description here
I tried to change font size of the content to LARGE but still it is not readable, even try to print in other page too . Nothing is working.

If you create a HUGE table and then resize it such that it fits on a page, it is obvious that not only the table shrinks but also the font size is reduced, isn't it? Using LARGE doesn't help a bit, your paperwidth won't increase.

I've played a little with your code. Removed all \LARGE modifiers and changed the table definition into \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{2.8cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{2cm}|}. It isn't brilliant, but readable. Might be a starting point for optimization

Do remember that \LARGE does not take arguments. \LARGE{Foo} is the same as \LARGE Foo. And note that it is never a good idea to resize a table. Design it properly instead.

Welcome to TeX.SX!

never use \resizebox{ on tables, as you see it will give you fonts of arbitrary size with no warning.

Maybe on topic, probably not: what does the / mean in your table entries?

Never use \resizebox with tables.
You can employ tabularx that will compute the column sizes by itself. I also provide a cleaner version without most of the rules (particularly the vertical ones).
To save space, I replaced / surrounded by spaces with \,/\,.
Also notice that the standard classes are set up for the caption below tables, so I used the caption package that reverses the preference.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{booktabs}% for the second realization

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\caption{Comparative Synthesis of Community Detection Metrics}
\label{tab:community_detection_synthesis}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\raggedright}X|>{\raggedright}X|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\splitcell{Graph \\ Classification}} &
\splitcell{Algorithm \\ Employed} &
\splitcell{Mod. \\ Measure} &
\splitcell{Inertial \\ Measure} &
\splitcell{Comm. \\ Count} &
\splitcell{Shared \\ Members} \\
\hline
Standard Graph & Louvain Algorithm \cite{r71}
 & 0.12\,/\,0.09 & 0.39\,/\,0.22 & 12\,/\,10 & 10 \\
\hline
Informational Single Graph & Combined Community Detection Algorithm \cite{r72}
 & 0.17\,/\,0.13 & 0.82\,/\,0.60 & 30\,/\,35 & 32 \\
\hline
Composite Graph & Generalized modularity optimization \cite{r73}
 & 0.21\,/\,0.18 & 0.67\,/\,0.50 & 20\,/\,16 & 17 \\
\hline
Dynamic Composite Information Graph & MCLDA
 & 0.25\,/\,0.21 & 0.94\,/\,0.97 & 24\,/\,9 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htp]
\centering

\caption{Comparative Synthesis of Community Detection Metrics}
\label{tab:community_detection_synthesis_second_version}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright}X>{\raggedright}Xcccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\splitcell{Graph \\ Classification}} &
\splitcell{Algorithm \\ Employed} &
\splitcell{Mod. \\ Measure} &
\splitcell{Inertial \\ Measure} &
\splitcell{Comm. \\ Count} &
\splitcell{Shared \\ Members} \\
\midrule
Standard Graph & Louvain Algorithm \cite{r71}
 & 0.12\,/\,0.09 & 0.39\,/\,0.22 & 12\,/\,10 & 10 \\
\addlinespace
Informational Single Graph & Combined Community Detection Algorithm \cite{r72}
 & 0.17\,/\,0.13 & 0.82\,/\,0.60 & 30\,/\,35 & 32 \\
\addlinespace
Composite Graph & Generalized modularity optimization \cite{r73}
 & 0.21\,/\,0.18 & 0.67\,/\,0.50 & 20\,/\,16 & 17 \\
\addlinespace
Dynamic Composite Information Graph & MCLDA
 & 0.25\,/\,0.21 & 0.94\,/\,0.97 & 24\,/\,9 & 4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\end{document}


You may also want to try the effect with \small added after \centering.


If you apply \resizebox to tables you have no chance of consistent font sizes. Also size commands do not take an argument so \LARGE XXX not \LARGE{XXX} but you do not want size commands within the table.
This may be closer to usable, although I would remove the horizonatl and vertical rules (see booktabs package)

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Comparative Synthesis of Community Detection Metrics}
\vspace{1em}
\label{tab:community_detection_synthesis}
\newcommand\hd[1]{\textbf{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}
\newcommand\citer{????}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\small
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  |>{\raggedright}p{2.9cm}|
  >{\raggedright}p{2.1cm}|
  c|c|c|c|
  @{}}
\hline
  \hd{Graph\\ Classification} &
  \hd{Algorithm\\ Employed} &
   \hd{Mod.\\ Measure}& \hd{Inertial\\ Measure} &
   \hd{Comm.\\ Count} & \hd{Shared\\ Members}\\ \hline

Standard Graph & Louvain Algorithm \citer71 & 0.12 / 0.09 & 0.39 / 0.22 & 12 / 10 & 10 \\ \hline
Informational Single Graph & Combined Community Detection Algorithm \citer72 & 0.17 / 0.13 & 0.82 / 0.60 & 30 / 35 & 32 \\ \hline
Composite Graph & Generalized modularity optimization \citer73 &  0.21 / 0.18 & 0.67 / 0.50 & 20 / 16 & 17 \\ \hline
Dynamic Composite Information Graph & MCLDA & 0.25 / 0.21 & 0.94 / 0.97 & 24 / 9 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}


Thanks a lot David. It worked
